# "childNodes" not fetching all child nodes for SVG object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, graph, svg

I am trying implement  dynamic line plot using SVG polyline. There are multiple graphs (so multiple SVGs ) under multiple tabs. Tabs are implemented by keeping SVGs under multiple divs and hiding all divs except the currently selected tab.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%" id="svg1">
        <line style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1" y2="25%" x2="100%" y1="25%" x1="0"/>
        <text style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt" y="24%" x="20" id="label_1_75">2.475 tab1units</text>

        <line style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1" y2="50%" x2="100%" y1="50%" x1="0"/>
        <text style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt" y="49%" x="20" id="label_1_50">1.650 tab1units</text>

        <line style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1" y2="75%" x2="100%" y1="75%" x1="0"/>
        <text style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt" y="74%" x="20" id="label_1_25">0.825 tab1units</text>


        <polyline style="fill-opacity:0;stroke:brown;stroke-width:1" points="0,300 0,340000000 5,340000000 10,340000000 15,340000000 20,340000000 25,340000000" id="custgraph_graph_1_1"/>


        <polyline style="fill:red;fill-opacity:0.4;stroke:red;stroke-width:1" points="0,300 0,340000000 5,340000000 10,340000000 15,340000000 20,340000000 25,340000000 " id="custgraph_graph_1_2"/>


        <line id="custgraph_del_line_1_15" x1="15" y1="0" x2="15" y2="100%" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1"/>
        <text id="custgraph_del_text_1_15" x="20" y="15" style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt">4m</text>
        <line id="custgraph_del_line_1_315" x1="315" y1="0" x2="315" y2="100%" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1"/>
        <text id="custgraph_del_text_1_315" x="320" y="15" style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt">3m</text>
        <line id="custgraph_del_line_1_615" x1="615" y1="0" x2="615" y2="100%" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1"/>
        <text id="custgraph_del_text_1_615" x="620" y="15" style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt">2m</text>
        <line id="custgraph_del_line_1_915" x1="915" y1="0" x2="915" y2="100%" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1"/>
        <text id="custgraph_del_text_1_915" x="920" y="15" style="fill:#999999; font-size:9pt">1m</text>
    </svg>
```

These SVGs have line and text elements as child nodes for showing grids (axes). As these grids are dynamic based on browser size I am recreating the grids each time a tab is selected. And whenever a tab is selected I am deleting the grid lines  under all the other tabs.

```
    for (var i = width<%=tabnum[i]%> % (step<%=tabnum[i]%> * 60); i < width<%=tabnum[i]%>; i += step<%=tabnum[i]%> * 60)
    {
        var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
            line.setAttribute('id','custgraph_del_line_<%=tabnum[i]%>_'+i );
            line.setAttribute('x1', i);
            line.setAttribute('y1', 0);
            line.setAttribute('x2', i);
            line.setAttribute('y2', '100%');
            line.setAttribute('style', 'stroke:black;stroke-width:0.1');

        var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
            text.setAttribute('id','custgraph_del_text_<%=tabnum[i]%>_'+i );
            text.setAttribute('x', i + 5);
            text.setAttribute('y', 15);
            text.setAttribute('style', 'fill:#999999; font-size:9pt');
            text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round((width<%=tabnum[i]%> - i) / step<%=tabnum[i]%> / 60) + 'm'));

        label_<%=tabnum[i]%>_25.parentNode.appendChild(line);
        label_<%=tabnum[i]%>_25.parentNode.appendChild(text);
    }
```

For this I am calling "childNodes" method on all the other SVG objects. The problem is that I am not getting all the child nodes. When I view the DOM in firebug, I can see that only some of the children are getting deleted.

```
            childlist=label_<%=tabnum[i]%>_25.parentNode.childNodes;
            for(i = 0; i < childlist.length; i++)
            {

                if(typeof childlist[i].id !== "undefined")
                {        
                    if (childlist[i].id.indexOf("custgraph_del_") == 0) 
                    {

                        label_<%=tabnum[i]%>_25.parentNode.removeChild(childlist[i])

                    }
                }
            }
```

So sometime when I navigate to another tab and come back, I see that some old grid lines still persist along with the newly created grid lines.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be removing items of the collection while looping it. So, as you progress in your loop and remove items, the index does not reference the same item as in the original array. Each time you remove an item, you skip the next because it is now placed at the index that you just tested.

A classic trick to work around this is to loop the array backwards, so that you only ever remove items at the end of it.

PS: you may consider [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) to help in your project.

Comment: Yeah...I had heard of that issue before. But didnt think it would apply in my case. Anyways it worked. Thanks !!